# After upgrading to 18.04 from 16.04, my xmind doesn't work anymore!

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I double click the app's icon in the dock, then it displays the welcome page, and afterwards no reflection in the screen.
I used the command `ps -ef` to find out there is no xmind process.

Comment: Run xmind from command line. If an error occurs, you should see it as output on the terminal.

Comment: well. thank you for your suggestion. next week I  try it in my work pc.

Comment: then I found a solution. append a config item "--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM" in the tail of XMind.ini, and xmind is work.

Comment: Post it as an answer and, after a day (or two), accept it as best answer.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you, wczmatthew, for [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031889/after-upgrading-to-18-04-from-16-04-my-xmind-doesnt-work-anymore/1034269#comment1681541_1031889)

It works with Ubuntu 18.04, XMind8 update 4 x64.

> I found a solution. Append a config item `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` at the end of `XMind.ini`, and XMind works.

I'd be interested to know how you arrived at that solution.

Comment: Also it works (--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM at the end of XMind.ini) with Xmind 8 update 7 (today 10.05.2018 it is last edition).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that worked for me, with XMind 7.5 update1.

Crash of `Xmind` is due to your Java version. Install [OpenJDK Version 8](http://apt://openjdk-8-jdk) and select the default Java version using the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```